# How to find data based on multiple column values in excel using apache POI

Tags: java, excel, maven, apache-poi

I am using the apache poi for reading and writing values to excel file with java. I have below excel file, from that file i need to fetch data which comes under my required criteria.

| Application | CaseID | FeeType | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AppA | 1234 | Security | Add Comments |
| AppB | 1235 | Other | Case created |
| AppA | 1236 | Security | Added Comments |

In my code I want to get all the cases which comes under below criteria,
Application set to "AppA",Fee Type set to "Security" and Comments with "Add Comments".

I used below code to filter using two columns for search criteria, but i cannot add the third criteria. Please help me.

```
ArrayList<Object> ApplicationCases = new ArrayList<Object>();

    for (Row row : sheetName) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING) {
                if (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().equals(requiredCellContent1)) {
                    int rowNumber = row.getRowNum();

                    XSSFRow row1 = sheetName.getRow(rowNumber);
                    XSSFCell selectedCellValue = null;

                    short cellcount = row1.getLastCellNum();

                    for (int i = 0; i < cellcount; i++) {

                        if (row1.getCell(i).getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim()
                                .equals(requiredCellContent2)) {
                            selectedCellValue = row1.getCell(1);
                            ApplicationCases.add(selectedCellValue);

                        } else if (selectedCellValue == null || row1.getCell(i).getCellType() == CellType.BLANK) {
                        }
                    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you so something like below

```
Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();
while(rows.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rows.next();
    String app = row.getCell(0).getRichStringCellValue().getString();
    String feeType = row.getCell(2).getRichStringCellValue().getString();
    String comment = row.getCell(3).getRichStringCellValue().getString();
    
    if(app.equals("AppA") && feeType.equals("Security") && comment.equals("Add Comments")) {
        //Here is your condition satisfied
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give me the entire code of this. I have similar issue. were i have excel file and i need to put certain rows only in another excel file using java

Comment: Sure, what exactly is the issue u r facing , u can create a new post for the same.